# How to pass two arguments to function from different sources with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm building a tic tac toe game and want to let the player choose whether to be X or O.

So when a player clicks a square on the board, they feed the clickButton function with id of the button they just clicked. This is the button for the first square on the board.

```
<input class="myButtons" type="button" id="button1" onclick="clickButton('button1')"></input>
```

The function takes the button id (param btn) and changes the value of the button. The value of a button is what's displayed on it in text, so by changing the value to X I mark the button with a giant X. If the first player to go is always X, then I can just set this equal to X, but I want the player to be able to choose whether to be X or O so I have it set to a variable.

```
function clickButton(btn, player) {
  // Add value to button.
  document.getElementById(btn).value = player;
```

I built a pair of buttons marked X and O.

```
<input type="button" id="playerX" value="X" onclick="clickButton(null,'X')"></input>
<input type="button" id="playerO" value="O" onclick="clickButton(null, 'O')"></input>
```

I want to pass the player argument to the function clickButton. I get an error saying that I can't assign a value of null to the button's value. Passing an empty string or something like that breaks the functionality of my game.

Is there any way to send only the second param of clickButton from one of my second pair of buttons?

Comment: Shouldnt you pass the arguments like so. ? onclick="clickButton(null,'X')"

Comment: Yes, sorry that was a mistake copying my code over to here

Comment: The error is still Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null

Comment: That's because document.getElementById(null) returns null and ``.value`` cannot be called on null

Comment: Show us the code for `clickButton`

Answer (score 0):

SO basically you are sending a null value to your function. So document.getelementById(null) is throwing an exception. Try this

```
function clickButton(btn, player) {
  // Add value to button.
if(btn == null)
 //assign some value to player1
else
  document.getElementById(btn).value = player;
}
```

The getElementById cannot find the id as it is null.

Comment: That's not really it. Thanks for posting.

Answer (score 0):

onclick=

Executes a javascript function.
So passing "null,clickbutton('x')" doesn't work, and will never work, it doesn't make any sense.  (I'm not sure how to explain why, which is why it sounds mean, sorry.)

If I understand correctly what you wanted, I passed in the correct paramaters into your clickButton function.

```
<input type="button" id="playerX" value="X" onclick="clickButton(getElementById('playerX'), 'X')"></input>

<input type="button" id="playerO" value="O" onclick="clickButton(getElementById('playerO'), 'O')"></input>
```

getElementById('playerX') 
will search for the element you just created as 'playerX'.

Alternatively, you can alter clickButton to this

```
function clickButton(event, player) {
  // Add value to button.
  event.target.value = player;
```

And you would have to update your elements to

```
<input type="button" id="playerX" value="X" onclick="clickButton(event, 'X')"></input>
```

Both are acceptable solutions.
Hope that helped

Comment: So the two buttons are not part of the board. They are separate from the board and mean "Before we start playing, choose if you will use X or O for the rest of the game". I can already change the value of the buttons on the board.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to find an element's value, however, you are not supplying element id to the function.

Currently, this is what is hapenning :

```
function clickButton(null, 'X') {
  // Add value to button.
  document.getElementById(null).value = player;
}
```

You cant pass `null` to `document.getElementById()` and hence the error

Change the code to below:

```
  <input type="button" id="playerX" value="X" onclick="clickButton(this.id,'X')"></input>
  <input type="button" id="playerO" value="O" onclick="clickButton(this.id, 'O')"></input>
```

Comment: So these two buttons are not on the board. They are outside the board, and are supposed to mean "Before we start playing, choose if you will be Xs or Os. I'm not trying to pass this.id because I don't want to change the value of the "Choose X or Y" buttons.  Know what I mean?

Comment: Got you. In that case, @Scott's Answer should work fine, I guess

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't even need the `clickButton` function, much less pass anything to it. Just keep track of which button the player initially picked (x or o).

Second, don't use inline HTML event handlers (onXyz=...) as they create spaghetti code, create global event handling wrapper functions and modify the value of `this` in your event handlers.

Instead, use the DOM Standard Event Model's `.addEventListener()` method:

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){

  // This code will execute as soon as all the DOM elements have been parsed

  var player = null;

  var playerX = document.getElementById("playerX");
  var playerO = document.getElementById("playerO");

  playerX.addEventListener("click", function(){
    player = this.value;
  });

  playerX.addEventListener("click", function(){
    player = this.value;
  });


  // Wire each button up to a function that sets that button's value
  // to x or o accordingly.
  var theButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".myButtons");

  for(var i = 0; i < theButtons.length; ++i){
    theButtons[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
        this.value = player;
    });
  }

});
```

Now, when a button gets clicked, it will simply change its value to `X` or `O`, depending on which initial button the player picked.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not positive what you are going for.  You want your playerX and playerO buttons to override the current player?  Like this :

**UPDATE**: I read in your other comments that you only want the player buttons to be available before the game, so I adjusted my code to accommodate.

```js
var player = 'O';
setPlayer = function(new_player){
 document.getElementById('player'+player).className = '';
  player=new_player?new_player:player=='X'?'O':'X';
  document.getElementById('player'+player).className = 'turn';
}
startGame = function(){
 document.getElementById('playerX').disabled = true;
  document.getElementById('playerO').disabled = true;
  document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = "Who's turn is it?";
  document.getElementById('board').className = '';
}
var btns = document.querySelectorAll('.myButtons');
for(var i=0;i<btns.length;i++){
 btns[i].onclick=function(e) {
    var btn = e.target;
    if(btn.value)return;
    btn.value = player;
    setPlayer();
  }
}
document.getElementById('playerX').onclick=function(){setPlayer('X');startGame()};
document.getElementById('playerO').onclick=function(){setPlayer('O');startGame()};
setPlayer('X');
```

```css
.myButtons{
  min-width:2em;
  margin:0;
}
@keyframes flash {  
  50% { background-color:#9999FF; }
}
.turn{
  animation: flash 2s linear infinite;
}
.hidden{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<div id='board' class='hidden'>
  <input class="myButtons" type="button" id="button1" />
  <input class="myButtons" type="button" id="button2" />
  <input class="myButtons" type="button" id="button3" /><br>
  <input class="myButtons" type="button" id="button4" />
  <input class="myButtons" type="button" id="button5" />
  <input class="myButtons" type="button" id="button6" /><br>
  <input class="myButtons" type="button" id="button7" />
  <input class="myButtons" type="button" id="button8" />
  <input class="myButtons" type="button" id="button9" /><br><br>
</div>
<div id='player_select'>
  <div id='message'>Who do you want to be?</div>
  <input type="button" id="playerX" value="X" />
  <input type="button" id="playerO" value="O" />
</div>
```